# Kruskal Algorithm in C - can't save to file

Tags: c, algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I'm having a problem with saving my results to output file. Probably something's wrong with the function, but I can't find it and fix it. Does anybody know what's wrong ?

PROGRAM'S CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int **str;
int *tab;

void read(){
    int n = 1;
    char help_sign;
    FILE *fp = fopen("In0303.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Blad odczytu z pliku!");
    }

    while((help_sign = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if (help_sign == '\n'){
            n++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void gen(){
    int i, n;
    int **str;

    str =(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        str[i] = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    }
}

void load_date(){
    int i, n;
    int **str;

    FILE *fp = fopen("In0303.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%d" , &str[i][0]);
        fscanf(fp, "%d" , &str[i][1]);
        fscanf(fp, "%d" , &str[i][2]);
        str[i][3]=0;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void gen_tab(){
    int i, n, k = 0;
    int **str;
    int *tab;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (str[i][0] > k) k = str[i][0];
        if (str[i][1] > k) k = str[i][1];
    }

    tab = (int*)malloc(k*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
        tab[i] = i + 1;
    }
}

void sort(){
    int i, n, j,tmp;
    int **str;

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            if (str[i][2] > str[j][2]){
                tmp = str[i][0];
                str[i][0] = str[j][0];
                str[j][0] = tmp;
                tmp = str[i][1];
                str[i][1] = str[j][1];
                str[j][1] = tmp;
                tmp = str[i][2];
                str[i][2] = str[j][2];
                str[j][2] = tmp;
            }
        }
}

int min(int x, int y){
    if (x > y) return y;
    else return x;
}

int max(int x, int y){
    if (x < y) return y;
    else return x;
}

void make(){
    int i, j, min1, max1, p, q, n, k;
    int *tab;
    int **str;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (tab[((str[i][0])-1)] != tab[((str[i][1])-1)]){
            str[i][3] = 1;
            min1 = min(tab[((str[i][0])-1)], tab[((str[i][1])-1)]);
            max1 = max(tab[((str[i][0])-1)], tab[((str[i][1])-1)]);

            for (j = 0; j < k; j++){
                if (tab[j] == max1)
                    tab[j] = min1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void save(){
    int i, n;
    int **str;
    int *tab;

    FILE *g = fopen("Out0303.txt","w");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (str[i][3] == 1){
            fprintf(g, "%d ", str[i][0]);
            fprintf(g, "%d ", str[i][1]);
            fprintf(g, "%d\n", str[i][2]);
        }
    }
    fclose(g);
}

int main(){
    read();
    gen();
    load_date();
    gen_tab();
    sort();
    make();
    save();

    printf("Wyniki zapisane do pliku!\n");
    free(str);
    free(tab);
    return 0;
}
```

THIS IS INPUT FILE ("In0303.txt"):

```
9 17
2 3 8 4 9 8
1 3 3 6 4 5 9 6
2 6 4 4 9 1
2 5 3 4 5 3 9 2
4 3 6 1 9 5
5 1 7 5 9 2
6 5 8 4 9 2
1 4 7 4 9 2
1 8 2 6 3 1 4 2 5 5 6 2 7 2 8 2
```

AND THIS IS WHAT SHOULD BE CREATED IN OUTPUT FILE: ("Out0303.txt"):

```
17
3 9 [1]
5 6 [1]
4 9 [2]
6 9 [2]
7 9 [2]
8 9 [2]
1 2 [3]
1 8 [4]
```

Comment: Why not use freopen function to redirect the standard output

Answer (score 3):

Offhand - in your save function, you don't assign to "n"

Expanding a bit.  You seem to want to use "n" as a global variable but you are declaring local instances of it so the value isn't retained across the functions.   You could either make it global or pass it around.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to DrC answers:

this piece of code:

`for (i = 0; i < n; i++){`

does very little if you do not set n, you have this mistake in gen(), gen_tab(), load(), save() and pretty much every other function.

Comment: Would you show the change in one of these functions ? I'm so new in programming :)

Comment: @MaciejJanuszewski: You probably need to change `read()` to `int read(void)`, initialize `int n = 0;`, and return `n` from the function.  The main code will then have `int n = read(); if (n > 0) { gen(n); load_date(n); ... }`, so you pass `n` to each function.  However, I fear there are other problems awaiting you, starting in `load_date()`.

Comment: Ok. Now it says to each function about arguments(). --> function does not take 1 arguments.

Comment: YOu need to change the function arguments, such as gen( int n)